# PySpark - Parse CSV file with UTF-16 encoding

Tags: pyspark, encoding

I have a CSV file which has UTF-16 LE encoding.

I am able to parse the data using below code (Spark 2.4.5):

```
df = spark.read \
    .schema('`my_id` string') \
    .option('sep', '\t') \
    .option('header', 'true') \
    .option('encoding', 'UTF-16') \
    .csv(my_path)
```

The Source data looks like this

```
my_id

123
456
```

When using `df.show()` or writing the data to Parquet `df.repartition(1).write.mode('append').format('parquet').save(my_target_path')` I get the below output

```
my_id
�
123�
456�
```

Opening the raw file in notepad++, i can see the below (note: Notepad++ used `UCS-2 LE BOM`)

[image]

When I open the file using VsCode, it uses `UTF-16 LE`

[image]

**Question**: Is it possible for me to use native spark.read.csv() to avoid the additional character which get added at the end of each line?

Comment: what do you mean by `The spark dataframe returns`? Did you use `.show()` to print it out? `.show()` might have used an incorrect encoding.

Comment: I have updated question to clarify how data is show/written out

Answer (score 2):

I found a resolution after doing some more digging. Enabling `multiline` resolved my issue. Data is being parsed without the extra `�` characters.

```
df = spark.read \
    .schema('`my_id` string') \
    .option('sep', '\t') \
    .option('header', 'true') \
    .option('encoding', 'UTF-16') \
    .option('multiline', 'true') \
    .csv(my_path)
```

There are 2 Spark issues which helped my analysis:

1. [SPARK-32961](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32961) - "*For the issue itself, I am almost 100% sure we can't fix with multiLine disabled*"
2. [SPARK-32965](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32965)